# Creating an rotating cone with dynamic segments using papervision

Tags: apache-flex, flash, papervision3d

I'm trying to create a rotating cone using papervision where all the segments can be filled with a color / image separately. So just like you can use a MaterialsList to render all the sides from a Cube separately.
Also I'd like to be able to check if a specific segment is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

(if you're still listening)
Easiest way I can think of is to apply texture to cone. Use some test texture with colored squares to learn how it maps to object; then you can replace patterns to your colored segments.
If you want to get perfectly sharp boundaries between segments, you should construct your cone yourself and assign material to each segment.